# Function calling in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to pass my filename from abc.m file to xyz.m file...without any return.
Please tell me the syntax to be written in both the files.I tried something like this:
In abc.m file:

```
xyz(filename);
```

In xyz.m file:

```
xyz(filename);
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  What do you mean by "without any return"?

Comment: It won't return anything as you have written it. WTP?????

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB functions are defined like this:

```
function y = MyAddFunction(x, n)
   y = x + n;
end
```

and are called as usual:

```
foo = MyAddFunction(10, 5);
```

If you want multiple output values you can define the output as such:

```
function [y1 y2] = MyOtherFunction(x)
   y1 = x + 3;
   y2 = y1 + 5;
end
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass them. MATLAB may just treat it as a string.

Comment: yes it will work, but as Parag states, Matlab will treat them as strings, so this method should also be responsible for first checking that a filename/file actually exists on the computer, open it for read/write, perform some operations, and finally close the file handle (and then continue with the next filename). I also suggest you do output some way of knowing if the requested files were successfully updated or not. happy coding!

Comment: It says that the variable is undefined...:(

Comment: Please edit your post/question with some actual code! AND clearly state what your function is suppose to do. Are you executing one matlab function within another, or, are you sending a list of filenames to a matlab function? its still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you're asking is, how do you write the function in xyz.m so that it doesn't have a return value, and will operate on the filename that you pass it from the function in abc.m.

If this is right, then the answer is quite simply that you define your function xyz without a return variable at all, like this:

```
function xyz(filename)
    %code goes here
end
```

And then, in abc.m, simply call it as `xyz(filename)`. So long as both m files are in appropriate places so that matlab can see them, it'll work.

The filename should be a string. I don't believe you can pass a file ID from fopen, if that's what you want to do, although it's possible that an open file is accessible from any function (I haven't really tested that).